# No Space between toprule and caption in the table

Tags: tables, captions

I would like to have no space between the toprule and caption.

the code for the table looks like this:

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{sgame}
\usetheme{Pittsburgh}
\usepackage{sgame, tikz} % Game theory packages
\usetikzlibrary{trees, calc} % For extensive form games
\usepackage{subfig} % Manipulation and reference of small or sub figures and tables
\usepackage{hyperref} % To create hyperlinks within the document
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Input encoding and font encoding 
\usepackage{setspace} % Setting the spacing between lines
\usepackage{amsthm, amsmath, amsfonts, mathtools, amssymb} % Math packages 
\usepackage{sgame, tikz} % Game theory packages
\usetikzlibrary{trees, calc} % For extensive form games
\usepackage{subfig} % Manipulation and reference of small or sub figures and tables
\usepackage{hyperref} % To create hyperlinks within the document
\usepackage{multirow,array}
\usepackage{caption}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\captionsetup[table]{position=bottom} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{color}   
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\def\table{\def\figurename{Table}\figure} % necessary to merge the list of tables with the list of figures
\let\endtable\endfigure % necessary to merge the list of tables with the list of figures
\useoutertheme{miniframes} 
\useinnertheme{circles}
\usefonttheme[stillsansserifmath]{serif}
\useoutertheme{miniframes} 
\useinnertheme{circles}
\usefonttheme[stillsansserifmath]{serif}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % I’m accustomed to always loading it...
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mwe}

\date[12. Dezember 2019]{12. Dezember 2019}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.0000\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in foot}\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.23\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.78\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][left]
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcommand*{\SuperScriptSameStyle}[1]{%
  \ensuremath{%
    \mathchoice
      {{}^{\displaystyle #1}}%
      {{}^{\textstyle #1}}%
      {{}^{\scriptstyle #1}}%
      {{}^{\scriptscriptstyle #1}}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\oneS}{\SuperScriptSameStyle{*}}
\newcommand*{\twoS}{\SuperScriptSameStyle{**}}
\newcommand*{\threeS}{\SuperScriptSameStyle{*{*}*}}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{table}[h] 
\caption*{\tiny Tabelle 1: Gesch\"azte Parameter, abh\"angige Variable: $Y$ = winpercent\strut}
\scalebox{0.4}{%
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
\toprule \\
Intercept & \color{blue} chocolate & \color{orange}fruity & caramel & \color{blue}peanutyalmondy & nougat \\ 34.534\threeS & 19.748\threeS  & $9.422$\twoS & $2.224$ &$10.071$\threeS &   $0.804$ \\ \color{blue} crispedricewafer & \color{red} hard & bar & pluribus & \color{blue} sugarpercent & pricepercent \\ $8.919$\oneS & -$6.165$\oneS & $0.442$ & -$0.854$ & $9.087$\oneS & -$5.928$ \\ 
\bottomrule 
    \multicolumn{6}{l}{%
  \begin{minipage}{11.5cm}%
   \itshape {Hinweis: Sternchen bedeuten Signifikanz zu: \oneS 10\%, \twoS 5\% und \threeS 1\%} 
  \end{minipage}%
}
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a ready-to-be-compiled code?

Comment: @Bernard i added the whole packages which i used for my work

Comment: The packages related to your problem will be enough, and the document class.

Comment: Isn't it a beamer document?

Comment: In your preamble you load some package twice ... also you load declaration for `beamer`, but use `article`! Please make a Minimal Working Example (MWE), a small but complete document which reproduce your problem.

Comment: yes it is sorry! \documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}

Comment: wanted to upload a photo for my problem. but unfortunately i was not able. hope that u guys can still help

Comment: `\captionsetup[table]{position=bottom}` means: I want space above the caption but no space below the caption. That's the reason why you don't get any space between caption and table. Change this to `\captionsetup[table]{position=top}` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You maybe like to obtain the following table format:

[image]
 I didn't bother with your beamer style. For table I use  `booktabs`, `tabularx`, `threeparttable` and `\siunitx` packages:

```
\documentclass[table, dvipsname, ngerman]{beamer}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx, threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \small
Gesch\"azte Parameter, abh\"angige Variable: $Y$ = winpercent\par\smallskip
    \begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} *{6}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} @{}}
    \toprule
Intercept \textcolor{blue}{chocolate}
    & \textcolor{orange}{fruity}& caramel           & \textcolor{blue}{peanuty\-almondy}  
    & nougat                    &                           \\  \addlinespace
34.534\tnote{*} 
    & 19.748\tnote{***}         &  9.422 \note{**}  &  2.224  
    & 10.071\tnote{***}         &  0.804                    \\  \addlinespace
\textcolor{blue}{crisped\-ricewafer} 
    & \textcolor{red}{hard}     & bar               & pluribus 
    & \textcolor{blue}{sugar\-percent}    & price\-percent  \\  \addlinespace
8.919\tnote{*}
    & $-6.165$\tnote{*}         &  0.442            & $-0.854$ 
    &  9.087\tnote{*}           & $-5.928$                  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]\scriptsize
\item[]\textit{Hinweis}: Sternchen bedeuten Signifikanz zu: 
\item[*]:    \SI{10}{\%}, 
\item[**]:   \SI{6}{\%} und 
\item[***]:  \SI{1}{\%}.
  \end{tablenotes}%
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Note:

- the˙beamer`package load some packages as are`geometry˙, `xcolor`, ... , `\hyperref`, therefore those packages are not need to load again
- it is sufficient to load each package ones (please check your preamble again and remove all duplicates)
- in preamble load only packages which you use
- in table design is used `tabularx` table environment, which enable to write cells' contents in more lines
  `since you use words, which is not considered in`babel`  you need manually insert possible points of hyphenation
- for table notes is sensible to use `threeparttable` and its `\tnote` and `tablenotes`
- for formatting cells is better to use `\twxtcolor{<color>}{<colored words>}` than `\color{<color>}`
- for all units in presentation use `siunitx`

Comment: thank u @Zarko! it worked for me